# What is this extra geometry which cannot be edited in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, faces

I just saw this on the "bar" I'm trying to create, I can't edit it since it doesn't appear to be a face, what can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using any modifiers? (e.g. Solidify)

Comment: @Flaeon Yes for the cylinder.

Comment: On your second image I can clearly see edges responsible for this, there clearly IS geometry, it's just not selected. Have you tried switching to Edge mode or Vertex mode to select these sub-objects? Or try A to select all and see if it gets selected?

Answer (score 2):

That 'extra' geometry seems to be created by the modifier stack so can't be selected in edit mode unless you apply the modifiers.

I would dare say it actually looks like a face with a wrong normal producing that artifact with a solidify modifier. If that's the case in edit mode select all your geometry and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to Unify Normals and see if the artifact is gone.

**Edit**

Your problem are overlapping extra faces, you probably created them accidentally by extruding your faces and inadvertently creating zero sized faces.

Switch to face selection mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select and erase the extra zero sized faces by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, then select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.
After remove doubles by  access the Specials menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) > *Remove Doubles* et voilá mesh clean.

[image]

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/NydSbtg.gifv)

Comment: Can you share your blend file? It will be a lot easier to see what is going on and try to solve the problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rn68qgc3urcfou/C.blend?dl=0

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: It worked well for me as illustrated in the image above.

Where did it fail for you? What steps did you take?

Comment: I'm new, I don't really understand. I don't know how you selected the faces and why you clicked on delete and nothing deleted...

Comment: I updated the original answer with more keyboard shortcuts. You must switch to face selection mode first with Ctrl+Tab, and I did delete something. Look closely at the small dots I selected before deleting, they are gone afterwards. You can only see them in face selection mode, they are zero sized faces and are what is causing you trouble